# Can Software Architects predict of how microservice architectures will mature over time?

Tags: architecture, microservices, soa, software-design

In March 2014 ( just over four years ago at the time of this question ), James Lewis and Martin Fowler wrote:

> Many people believe that [decay of modularity over time] is less likely with microservices, since the service boundaries are explicit and hard to patch around. Yet until we see enough systems with enough age, we can't truly assess how microservice architectures mature.

Now that many MSAs have been built by a variety of businesses, do we have a general understanding of the maturation of these architectures? What do we know about what works as time goes forward? What do we know about what does not work?

Comment: This question is asking for an opinion, and is likely to draw subjective answers.

Comment: When we've just started to understand MSA, the FAAS comes fast from behind.

Comment: Actually there are lot of factors behind the architecture to evolve like based on business demand or consumer behaviour. Take example of Netflix they moved to Microservices because of Business demand then for improvement of consumer behaviour they also adapted reactive system. So for architect, it's all about some kind of special demand which causes them to keep on think how to mature architecture. As it is said :- “today's demands are simply not met by yesterday's software architectures”

Comment: I understand there's subjectivity involved in assessing an architecture. What I'm after is the validation / invalidation of architects beliefs about a project after time has passed. In choosing an MSA in 2014, it may be that an architect _believes that decay of modularity over time is less likely_: objectively, does an architect who implemented a system in 2014 believe that modularity has actually decayed by 2018?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is very subjective and will be dependant on how much architecture & design effort have been put upfront into the overall solution/system and how much governance controls are in place for architectural changes to the system around integrations, deployments, etc.

But from experience, I can (almost) absolutely guarantee that architectures evolve over time and different solutions will emerge out of unforeseen and/or unplanned functional and technical requirements. No architecture will stay intact in the face of agile, evolving requirements.

The other factor to take into consideration as well, is that tools, patterns, and techniques change very quickly in our industry. So, the longer it takes for a project to complete, the more exposure it has to a change in these areas. That's another fact (in my opinion)

What does not change, however, is the motivation behind those architectural decisions. The Why?
Architecture governance needs to capture those motivations and ensure that they are fulfilled with whatever evolving tool, pattern, or technique used in the long term.

For my own projects, I ensure that a big factor of any architecture decisions we make is driven by a balanced view of business drivers vs developer experience (DX) to ensure clarity, productivity, mastery, stability, quality, etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand there's a strong interpretation bias. But consider the phrasing of Lewis and Fowler's question: "many people believe...". You might rephrase my question as: "how often have architects validated their _beliefs_ about an MSA after four years have passed"?

Comment: I see. And I think there is no single answer here. architectures will evolve differently under changed circumstances and decisions. There is no pattern identified yet.